# How to change background color of UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicontainerview

I have a MainViewController and it has a container view. with few margin from edges.
Now i navigate to another view ViewController1. Suppose there i get an error for some region in ViewController1. then i want to change my MainViewController's background in red. so the view should look like this(screen shot are attached) where red border is MainViewController Background

[image]

and here is my code

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
var MainVC =  MainViewController()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MainVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
```

but its not working

Comment: Dear down voters. can you explain me y ?
waiting for you reply

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor. greenColor()
```

Comment: it will change color of current view. but i need to change color of initial view. which showing red in screen shot. 
if i do this then this will change pink color to green.

Comment: so you want the same colour scheme of two colours like as in snapshot?

Comment: if you find it useful plz upvote and accept my answer

Comment: no dear its not working 
i think you are getting me wrong . i want to change MainViewController background color in ViewController1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108504/discussion-between-museer-ansari-and-abhi).

Answer (score -5):

You can get any uiviewcontroller object from Navigation controller:

navigationController?.viewControllers;